# What is the use of ; in a single line command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, bash-script

What does `;` mean in single line scripts like this:

```
while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 '$$' || exit; done 2>/dev/null &
```

Does it mean new line, or "next command"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a separator of commands. Though in the first instance, it might be better to think of it as ending the `while` statement.

For example, if you wanted to do a loop while some command returns success, you would do something like

```
while test -f /foo; do some_command; done`
```

The semicolon is used to indicate the end of the arguments to `test`. Otherwise it would think that `do` is another argument to `test`.

However you can use newlines instead of the semicolon. The following would be exactly equivalent to the example above, just without any semicolons

```
while test -f /foo
do
some_command
done
```

In fact with bash, if you run the above command, and then after it finishes (or you CTRL+C it), if you go back in history (up arrow keys or whatnot), you'll notice it replaces the multi-line command with one using semicolons instead.

---

So yes, the syntax for things like `if` and `while` break normal shell behavior.
I've personally always thought the syntax is weird, as the `do` looks strange. But you get used to it.